# How would you evaluate $\sum_{j=0}^t \frac{j}{2^j}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

According to WolframAlpha, this evaluates to $2^{-t} (-t + 2^{t + 1} - 2)$.

Comment: (The question isn't an exact duplicate, but the accepted answer there gives the answer to this question as well.)

Answer (score 2):

Thats an AGP let the sum be $S $ . Multiplying this series by $\frac {1}{2 }$ to get $\frac {S}{2} $.Now subtract the two series to get a geometric series with $r=\frac {1}{2} $ . And hope you know summation of a geometric series.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

\begin{align} g(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0} ^{t}x^k=\frac{1-x^{t+1} }{1-x}\end{align}

You can do something with $g'(x)$ to get what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is basically brute force, but
$\sum_{j=0}^t\frac{j}{2^j}=\sum_{j=0}^t\sum_{i=1}^j\frac{1}{2^j}=\sum_{i=1}^t\sum_{j=i}^t\frac{1}{2^j}=\sum_{i=1}^t(2^{1-i}-2^{-t})=2-2^{1-t}-t2^{-t}$, which is the same as what Wolfram Alpha told you. The last two steps are from the formula for the partial sum of a geometric series, and the reason you wanted to do this strange splitting is because you know how to calculate those.

Comment: Can you justify the very first equality?

Comment: Yes, notice that the term inside the sum is independent of $i$, so we're just summing $j$ terms all equal to $\frac{1}{2^j}$.